# should we use a captcha for Sign Up?

Tags: captcha

I know it's not really a programming question but I don't know where to ask it.

Should i use a captcha in my sign up form ?

Facebook, twitter, foursquare, gowalla etc... don't use one (or not a visible one). Is there an invisible catpcha on theses sites ?

Thank you

UPDATE :
I have found a nice article about it : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/07/08/web-form-design-patterns-sign-up-forms-part-2/
Thanks for your answers

Comment: What is invisible captcha? :/

Comment: @Aris L. An invisible captcha is one that uses fields that are invisible to humans, but bait scripts into filling them out, so then when the data is POSTed, if the invisible field are filled in, then you have a good idea that a bot did it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't use a captcha for SingingEels, but I do require a valid email address. Users **have to** confirm their email address by clicking a link sent with a GUID upon creating a new account.

That validates a real human, and also prevents quick sign-ups for spam comments.

Comment: It does so better than a captcha... unless someone spent the time creating a program that would parse 'SingingEels' emails and open a browser window and navigate to the URL... but there are more captcha hacking programs than Eels sign-up hacking programs thus far :P

Comment: If you do not worry about bad guys targeting your specific website, adding a simple question to the signup form (eg. 2+2) should be as effective as e-mail validation, while being less troublesome for the users.

Comment: "open a browser window and navigate to the URL" - a program wouldn't do that. It would just send a `GET` request to all URLs contained within any emails received to the mailbox.

Comment: Requiring a valid email address is not the same as requiring a human to register..., if someone makes a bot that creates thousands of accounts with fake emails, your mailserver is going to be basically blacklisted...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use captcha code in SignUp page. But as far as security reason is concerned, you need to captcha code where you have any form. Because some one puts a robot for signup in your page at that you have to face a problem with your website. So for this purpose you need to add captcha not only in Signup page but every form you are using in your website.

Answer (score 0):

CAPTCHA helps prevent automated abuse of your site (such as comment spam or bogus registrations) 
it is advisable to use additional authenication methods, captcha, email authentication are most advisable.

Answer (score -2):

It is not advisable to use any captcha at all..

Also see;
https://web.archive.org/web/20140427021015/http://www.interfacegeek.com/dont-ever-use-captchas/

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: It's always a good idea, if you're referencing another site, to summarize the point made on that site because links don't last forever.